# Best Practice to define a list of consequent activities to close a Case

Tags: visual-workflow, case, process, management

as title said, I'm looking for a best practice or a standard SF solution to manage a Case creating a list of to-do activity in order to close the Case. For example an operator need to make some operations in a specific order:

1. Call the customer
2. Send an outbound request to an external system
   via a button on custom object page layout
3. Close the Case

What's the best way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look at using a flow to guide the service rep through the steps. This [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/flow) may be of interest. That coupled with some validation rules to ensure they fill out certain fields may be enough. However, what's "best" is probably something stackexchange cannot answer with limited info on your org/structure.

Comment: You're right, but I was only looking for something that could be useful in my case. Thank you for the tip about the flow, probably I will use this in order to achieve my goal. Thank you!